# Defensive Pact member drop leave the pact after reload

Tags: crusader-kings-2

My threat level is around 80-90%, as soon as it drops lower I declare another war. The limiting factor to my further expansion is the amount of opposing pacts...

But, quite often after I load the game many of pacts participants just drop the pact and... it looks like I can declare war without triggering everybody to attack myself.

I believe once it did fail as even though member I attack did not have pact, many countries did support him in war. And now, even if many leave the pact, I often am afraid to attack.

Anybody observed a similar behaviour? Is that a bug or some feature I don't understand. Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: If you let the game run for a few days do the characters that left the pact rejoin it?